# jQuery delay animate runs twice - how to use Stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic animation:

```
<div id="FPbl">text</div>
```

```
$("#FPbl").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
$("#FPbl").delay(2000).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 700);
```

The problem is, I am using a 'onepage' scroll pluguin, which seems to trigger the script each time a new section is loaded - causing the text above to appear on all 'slides'

How can I use the stop function, to make the script run only once per site load?

Comment: You have to show us what triggers the animation as well.

Comment: i think you have to set the counter variable to run the script only once per site load.

Comment: `.stop(true)`, before the `.animate`, probably.

Comment: Add a `class` when the animation completes and do not run the animation if that `class` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin refreshes the page then there is nothing we can do about it, but if you feel that its triggering this function twice then use a global variable as a flag and check it before animating.

also make use of callback functions

```
var globalFlag=0; //declare globally
if(globalFlag==0){
$("#FPbl").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700,function(){
$("#FPbl").delay(2000).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 700); 
globalFlag=1; // change it after required animation is completed
});
}
```

Comment: which stays? what is the content that you want to hide?

Comment: you want to hide bridging the gap?

Comment: yes, it is supposed to show only on the first page, but it appears again after. I am surprised of the level of help that is available here, I almost feel like I should offer to pay for you looking into this?

Comment: you need to reduce the delay and try $("#FPbl").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700,function()
try reducing it to 1000,
No mention

Answer (score 0):

1) Use jquery plugin,
2) Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#FPbl").fadeIn(1000);
setTimeout(function()
{
$("#FPbl").fadeOut(1000);
}, 3000);
});
</script>
```